# TF IDF Vectorizer not functioning properly

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, tfidfvectorizer

I am working on a text classification problem and using TFIDF vectorizer to generate text features.

Here is the code

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True,
                                                      # stop_words=English_Stopwords,
                                  ngram_range=(1,3),
                                   min_df=0.10, #  ignore terms that have a document frequency strictly lower than the given threshold
                                   max_df=0.80, 
                                  smooth_idf=True)        
fitted_vect = tfidf_vectorizer.fit(df_sample[TEXT_FEAT])
transformed_X_train = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(X_train)
transformed_X_val = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(X_val)
```

I looked up the vocabulary and it contains only 162 words while the stop words list is pretty huge. What is the problem here.

```
print(len(fitted_vect.vocabulary_))
# 162
print(len(fitted_vect.stop_words_))
# 16969712
```

Answer (score 0):

If the **only** problem is stopwords suppression, one could just add the argument *stop_words = 'english'* to the vectorizer.
*Note: It is noticed that there is a custom stop words list commented out in the question. Those stopwords can be appended to the existing ones if needed.*

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True,                                                     
                                  ngram_range=(1,3),
                                  stop_words = 'english',
                                   min_df=0.10, #  ignore terms that have a document frequency strictly lower than the given threshold
                                   max_df=0.80, 
                                  smooth_idf=True)
```